# Error: 'wcsncasecmp' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, macos, g++

I use wcsncasecmp inside c/c++ app.

Compile have following error:

```
error: 'wcsncasecmp' was not declared in this scope
```

Gcc 4.2.1, macos.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Have you included the relevant header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wcsncasecmp` is a GNU-specific function. It's not available on Mac OS X.

Comment: @xijingdai: some combination of `towlower` and `wcscmp` should do the trick.

Comment: appears it is available but only in 10.7 and above: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-binutils/2014-12/msg00189.html